# Is the language of Roman numerals ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

An ambiguous Language is a formal language for which there exists a string that can have more than one meaning (several possible meanings or interpretations). Multiple synthesis structures for a string.

**[Question]**
Are [Roman numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) an example of an ambiguous language?

Because there can be more then one representation for some number such as 1999, which 
can be written as `MDCCCCLXXXXVIIII`, `MCMXCIX`, or `MIM`.

I am confused. Sometimes I feel not, some time yes!

**EDIT**
[ANSWER]

Although there can be more than one representation of same magnitude in Roman Number System. That is basically Non-Positional Number System. But its possible to write [**Unambiguous Grammar for that can generate all possible/valid pattern in Roman Number System**](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/07-03-118).

[**Here is again a beautiful link**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/roman_numerals.html) that describe `symbol table`, `rule`  , `Grammar` for Roman number.

I am not sure about this but some authors says that: "*Roman numbers can be recognized by a regular expression, so you don't really need a context-free grammar.*" and a regular language can't be ambiguous.

Comment: Well, there *are* inherently ambiguous languages, but that is not your problem here.

Comment: @Raphael I know [there are](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648491/1673391) And yes set-of-all-possible-roman numbers (even if rule for more then 5000) is unambiguous.

Comment: More-over If we check definition of formal-grammars (or any represent) then set-of-language-symbol can't be infinite. And because formation rule of Roman number doesn't allow repetition of same number more than 3-times consecutively hence Roman-Numbers are finite in real (can't represent arbitrarily large magnitude) And so @reinierpost's answer is correct!! There are other problem with roman numbers formation rule is not readable --then concept of positional number system came(roman numbers are non-positional number system).

Answer (score 19):

A grammar (not a language!) is ambiguous if there is a word with two "essentially different" parses. Roman numerals are unambiguous - given a roman numeral, it has an unambiguous numerical value. The fact that this correspondence is not one-to-one is beside the point.

Comment: This is the way I think :) .. and it should be correct too!

Comment: This assumes that you call strings such as IXM invalid, and not Roman numerals. (I have seen IIX = 8 used historically, as well as VIII = 8, but I am fairly sure nobody ever used IXM.)

Answer (score 6):

You fell into the trap of thinking that formal language theory deals with meaning. It doesn't.

In formal language theory, a context-free language is ambiguous if some context-free grammar generates exactly that language, but no such grammar does so in such a way that each string in the language only has a single parse tree.

The language of [Roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) isn't completely standard, but I believe all versions have the property of being *finite*: I don't think 5000 can be represented, let alone a million. Every finite language is unambiguous: it can be generated by a grammar that directly produces each member string from the start symbol.

(UPDATE: Peter Shor's comments make it clear that this wasn't the case: apparently it was quite common to surround numbers with `C Ͻ` or `| |` to multiply them by 1000.  When this can be applied arbitrarily often, the language is no longer finite; when it can be done in arbitrary ways, it still doesn't become ambiguous when only `C Ͻ` is used; when `| |` is used, the interpretation may become ambiguous, but I still don't think the language becomes ambiguous in the formal, syntactic sense.)

Comment: 5000 = (V) or MMMMM.

Comment: So what is 50000?

Comment: (L), of course. Actually, the Romans would have written it more like ϹLϽ (with the two Ϲ's symmetric). Enclosing things in parentheses  multiplies them by 1000. If you allow multiple parentheses (I'm not sure whether the Romans used this; it certainly seems to have been rare), you can get any number.

Comment: Hmm, yes, Wikipedia mentions this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers); if arbitrarily many `Ϲ` and `Ͻ` are allowed, my answer becomes invalid: the resulting language is infinite (but still seems to be unambiguous). It also mentions an alternative with `|`, which may not be unambiguous (it isn't explained in sufficient detail).

Comment: The idea that the Romans, who successfully managed an empire with millions of people in it, couldn't count beyond 5000 is totally absurd. It does seem that the system for representing numbers above 5000 changed during the Roman empire, so the exact notation they used may have depended on the time period. It is also likely that there were times when two or more different notations were used. However, having two or three different notations for 1,000,000 (or do I mean 10^6?) should not cause a problem.

Comment: It's possible to count much higher than one's notation for numbers reaches by mixing in names for numbers ("50 thousand") or units ("3 days, 17 hours, 4 minutes and 6 seconds").

Comment: Well, we typically assign meaning to words given syntax trees, so it *is* a matter of formal language theory and related to ambiguity of grammars.

Comment: What I meant to say is that in formal language theory, the issue of ambiguity is not the issue of attaching different meanings to the same strings, just different parse trees - how parse trees are interpreted is a different matter.

Answer (score 4):

Its not ambiguous.

Note that if you are writing a smaller digit before a larger one, obviously that means you are subtracting. But notice that those digits must be comparable.
`I` would come before `V` and `X` only. `X` would come before `L` and `C` only. `C` before `D` and `M`.

Break the number and then combine their roman correspondents.

`49` is `40+9`. We dont write it as `IL`. We first convert `40`, then `9` so its `XLIX`.

`99` is not `IC`. Its `90 (XC)` + `9 (IX)` ie `XCIX`.

`499` is not `ID`. Its `400 (CD)` + `90 (XC)` + `9 (IX)` ie `CDXCIX`.

`999` is not `IM`. Its `900 (CM)` + `90 (XC)` + `9 (IX)` ie `CMXCIX`.

So, according to this

`1999` should be `MCMXCIX`. `1000 (M)` + `900 (CM)` + `90 (XC)` + `9 (IX)`.

And also `MDCCCCLXXXXVIIII` is an invalid representation. You can't have 4 consecutive same letters. Instead you convert it.

M*DCCCC*LXXXXVIIII $\rightarrow$ M*CM*LXXXXVIIII

MCM*LXXXX*VIIII $\rightarrow$ MCM*X*VIIII

MCMXC*VIIII* $\rightarrow$ MCMXC*IX*

This [online conversion tool](http://www.onlineconversion.com/roman_numerals_advanced.htm) might be helpful.

Comment: According to wikipedia, having 4 times the same symbol was actually common,

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing several concepts of ambiguity, and using your own
definition backward.

There is the concept of **semantic ambiguity**: is it possible to have
different meanings for the same string. In your case: is it possible
that 2 different numbers are written in the same way in Roman numerals.
The answer is clearly no, because there is a simple deterministic
algorithm to compute the value represented by a Roman numeral.

However, when you talk of formal language, you are considering only
syntactic structures (usually tree structure) associated to string
in accordance with the way these strings can be generated by a
grammar. Identifying a tree associated with a string is called
parsing.

Then there is the concept of **syntactic ambiguity**. Are there two
different ways to parse some numerals into a structure. I cannot answer
that since you do not give a formal definition of  the structure of
roman numerals.

But let us assume that you are only considering structure defined by a
context-free (CF) grammar. Then you may wonder whether the Roman numerals
can be generated by an **unambiguous CF grammar** (they can, though I did
not check the grammar on the site you discovered).  But there are CF
languages that will not have an unambigous grammar. Such CF languages are
said to be **inherently ambiguous**.

**Does syntactic ambiguity really matter?** Not necessarily if you are
only interested in the meaning of sentences, here in the integer values
represented by Roman numerals.  Syntactic structure is normaly used to define
semantic, that is, meaning. If the same sentence has two structure
because of grammatical ambiguity, that could be a problem. But it
could also be that the way meaning is associated with the structure of
a sentence (the parse tree) is such that it produces the same meaning
for all strucures corresponding to a same sentence. **Syntactic
ambiguity does not necessarily result in semantic ambiguity.**

The Romans numerals can be defined as a formal language, for example
with a CF grammar. But you are also associating a meaning with each
string, which means that you are considering more than a formal language.
Hence you should be clear whether you talk of syntactic ambiguity, or
of semantic ambiguity.

Now, you may have two distinct Roman numerals
that represent the same number, as you show in your question, and which is
confirmed by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals). For
example VIIII and IX. That is not ambiguity. It is a very common
situation when a given meaning can be expressed syntactically by
different strings. While you stated correctly that (semantic)
ambiguity is when a string can have more than one meaning.

To take it with natural language, the sentence "John sees a man with a
telescope" is ambiguous because you cannot determine whether John is
using a telescope, or whether the man is carrying one.

But the fact that both sentences "the dog eats the bone" and "the bone
is eaten by the dog" mean the same thing is not a problem for anyone.

From what I read in wikipedia, there is a finite number of Roman
numerals. Hence they can be trivially represented by a regular
grammar. And a regular grammar is an unambiguous CF grammar.
But that is a trivial argument that provides no insight.

What you want is a CF grammar that will identify as a tree the
organization of a Roman numeral so that it will be easier to
compute its meaning: the associated integer. This is possible in various
ways.

Comment: I know  a class of [ambiguous language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648491/1673391) exists. I discovered set of Roman Numbers as formal language  is **not** ambiguous. Yes two roman numbers can representation same magnitude but it doesn't makes set-of-all-roman-numbers an ambiguous language. In fact more than one expressions in set-of-math-expressions e.g `2 + 2 + 2` and `3 * 2`  represents same magnitude but it is unambiguous The same way- set-of-all-all-possible roman numbers are unambiguous. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The translation from Arabic numbers to Roman numbers is very straight forward and absolute not 'unambiguous'.

You can translate each Arabic digit to exact one Roman representation.

```
Arabic:    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
Roman:     I   II  III   IV    V   VI  VII VIII   IX

Arabic:   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90
Roman:     X   XX  XXX   XL    L   LX  LXX LXXX   XC

Arabic:  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900
Roman:     C   CC  CCC   CD    D   DC  DCC DCCC   CM

Arabic: 1000 2000 3000  
Roman:     M   MM  MMM
```

Combine a number from the highest to the lowest digit.

E.g.
1999 is (with space) `M CM XC IX` and together `MCMXCIX`.

Comment: This is indeed the modern formula, but it wasn't the only way the Romans did it. At some point, somebody decided that there should only be one Roman number for positive each integer, and come up with this system. MIM would have been perfectly acceptable to the Romans.

Comment: @petershor, can you cite some research that demonstrates this assertion? I don't disbelieve you, just want to know what has been done to discover this.

Comment: Look in the lower right corner of this [picture](http://www.the-romans.co.uk/gallery2/full/republic020.jpg) from the Arch of Augustus. You should see DCXXXIIX. And [here](http://datetime.mongueurs.net/divers/nombres-romains/Polla_via_popilia_da_reggio_a_capua.jpg) is DCCCCXVII from [this website](http://datetime.mongueurs.net/divers/nombres-romains/Roman_Numbers.html).

Comment: Also look for 4 in roman numerals on clocks, it is (somewhat) common to see IIII for it (not IV).